# icloud said it will not let me in for security purposes

Tags: icloud

icloud said it will not let me in for security purposes.  Suggested change of password.  Told me my birthday was wrong.  Then said it sent me email to change password and no show.  This is ongoing.

Answer (score 2):

Only Apple can help. If https://iforgot.apple.com is no help, you'll have to [ring them](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201232)